# Recursively check if an array represents a heap

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, heap

How do we check if an array represents a heap data structure recursively?
Assume it is an array of integers, and I am checking for max heap. 
The following is what I came up with, but I don't know if that is correct.

```
public static boolean isHeap(int[] arr) {
      if (arr = null)
           return false;
      return isHeapTree(arr, 0);
}

private static boolean isHeapTree(int[] arr, int i) {
           if (i = arr.length - 1)
               return true;
           // check if a parent's value is larger or equal to both of
           // its left child and right child
           else if (arr[i] >= arr[2i + 1] && arr[i] >= arr[2i + 2])
               return (isHeapTree(arr, 2i + 1) && isHeapTree(arr, 2i + 2));
           else
               return false;
}

is it possible a binary heap could be incomplete? say:
         100
        /   \
       50   20
      /  \    \
     30  40   26
```

Comment: do you really need it to be recursive>

Comment: Seems to be right.. What do you feel is wrong with it?

Comment: what if `2i + 1` is larger than `arr.length` what will isHeapTree(arr, 2i + 1) return ...

Comment: `is it possible a binary heap could be incomplete?` not in this fashion, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments:

- You definitely don't need the while loop - you always return after the first iteration
- `2i + 1` doesn't work in java, you need to use `2*i + 1`
- `arr[2*i + 1]` and `arr[2*i + 1]` may throw and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` so you need to either manually do a range check, or wrap it in a `try.. catch` block

Comment: Thanks for your help Denis. I was thinking using it check array index, that probably is the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when a heap is stored in an array, it is always packed to the left. In other words,  when the heap has `n` elements, the all elements in the array in the index range `[0, n-1]` contain elements. Every insert starts by placing the element at index `size()`, and then it jumps up until it is smaller than its parent.

So the approach you are taking can succeed.

Also note that in your code, you can deal with going out of bounds with a small change to your guard on top:

```
public static boolean isHeap(int[] arr, int size) {
  return (null == arr) ? false : isHeapTree(arr, size, 0);
}

private static boolean isHeapTree(int[] arr, int size, int i) {
  assert i >= 0;
  assert size <= arr.length;
  if (i >= size) return true;
  ...
```